# How to import external Java libraries in OpenTest framework?

Tags: automated-tests, opentest

I would like to find out how I can import external libraries into my tests? For example, if i use a Java library for random name/number generation, how do I go about using it in my tests?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I answer, I would advise that you should avoid using Java code, if you can. For example, a random name/number generator is very easy to implement in JavaScript and you can find plenty of ready-made examples out there. If it's JS code, you can easily embed it in your tests using one of the techniques described [here](https://getopentest.org/docs/scripting-support.html). Even better, you should use capabilities that are provided out-of-the-box with OpenTest: [$random](https://getopentest.org/reference/javascript-api.html#randommin-max) and [$randomString](https://getopentest.org/reference/javascript-api.html#randomstringlength-characterpool).

If you really need to use Java code, there are two ways to do it:

- The recommended way: create one or more custom OpenTest keywords as described [here](https://getopentest.org/tutorials/custom-keywords.html). This will make it easier for you to maintain your test suite in the future and it also makes it easier for other members of your team to leverage this work in their own tests, especially if they are not familiar with Java.
- The "quick and dirty" way: create a `user-jars` directory in your test actor's working directory and drop the JAR file in there. Then, call your Java code from JavaScript as described [here](https://getopentest.org/docs/scripting-support.html#advanced-concepts).