# How do I add Sikuli JAR file to OpenTest allowing for automation on Windows 7?

Tags: java, windows, sikuli, sikuli-script, opentest

The code below is in yaml and is designed to allow for support in executing Java using an external java library.

Currently, I receive an error indicating that the Class could not be found.

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sikuli.script.*
```

I have added the jar file to the folder name `user-jars` as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54560878/168617 and here: https://getopentest.org/docs/scripting-support.html#advanced-concepts

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/54560878/168617
# https://getopentest.org/docs/scripting-support.html#advanced-concepts
description: Login using SikuliX as driver
actors:
  - actor: WEB
    segments:
      - segment: 1
        actions:
          - description: Get content of file
          - script: |
              var Sikuli = Java.type("org.sikuli.script.*")
              var Files = Java.type("java.nio.file.Files");
              var Paths = Java.type("java.nio.file.Paths");
              var System = Java.type("java.lang.System");
              var JavaString = Java.type("java.lang.String");

              var content = new JavaString(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("C:/content.txt")), "UTF-8");
              System.out.println(content);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Java.type()` API requires that you specify the name of a single Java class, so you cannot use wildcards. For example:

```
var Screen = Java.type("org.sikuli.script.Screen");
var screen = new Screen();
screen.click("C:/images/test.png", 0);
```